# String class = operator

Tags: c++, string, substring

I'm working on building my own string class and I'm having some trouble with substring

```
// Substring operator
// reutns a substring from a given point
String String::Substring(int startPosition, int length) const{
    if(length==0)
        length = GetLength()+1; //Takes care of null terminator, im not worried about if length is imputed yet
    char* result = new char[length-startPosition]; // Assume it's not negative for the sake of just getting it to work, It would only be negative if it's user error
    for(int i=startPosition; i<length; i++)
        result[i] = Text[i]; //Since it will always  go from a given point to the end, the null terminator will transfer in the for loop.

    return result;
}
```

Text is the data member for the string class. I get a unhandled exception, Access violation reading location.

While I was debugging it was going through these processes

```
// Init-constructor for initializing this string with a C-string
String::String(const char* text){
    *this = text;
}
```

and

```
// Assigns C-string to this String
String& String::operator = (const char* text){
    // Delete the existing string first
    delete[] Text;

    // +1 accounts for null terminator
    int trueLength = GetLength(text)+1;

    // Allocate new memory
    Text = new char[trueLength];

    // Copy all characters from source into Text
    for ( int i = 0; i < trueLength; i++)
        Text[i] = text[i];

    return *this;
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, thanks for your help.

Comment: The biggest problem is you're writing your own string class.  Why?  There much more constructive ways to properly learn the language.

Comment: @Chad This is what he's doing - it's none of your business why. If you can't help, don't bother replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens when you create a String object using the `char*` constructor:

```
String::String(const char* text){
  *this = text;
}
```

None of the members are initialized yet, and you invoke `operator=`:

```
String& String::operator = (const char* text){
  // Delete the existing string first
  delete[] Text;
```

You delete member `Text`, even though you have not yet initialized it. Deleting an unitialized pointer yields undefined behavior. In this case, the behavior is an exception.

Either initialize `Text` to null in your constructor before invoking `operator=`, or do all of the work in your constructor, not your assignment operator.

Comment: I've actually thought about this, however that code is actually set in stone because my professor told me to do it in that way.

Comment: Which part of `String` did he constrain, and which part are you free to choose? If he said "Always invoke operator= from constructor.", then do that, but do it without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: The ones above are constrained so I don't think I should be messing with it. Honestly when I thought the return would be invoked it would just output the result and not even call operator =

Comment: After some thought I decided to just change it because it was the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate `length-startPosition` you could very well be using a negative number.

Do the new with just length:

```
char* result = new char[length];
```

EDIT:

Start copying from `i=0` and set the byte after the last copied character to null:

```
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    result[i] = Text[i+startPosition];

result[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to do "just length". What if I want a 5 characters substring of 1GB long string? Should I double the memory footprint? I'd rather check for offset bounds and then do what he has done.

Comment: @VladLazarenko, isn't length the number of wanted characters?

Comment: He's also writing to result with the startPosition added, which may overrun the buffer (and will certainly write to the wrong position).

Comment: Yea the null terminator is taken care of when I initialize length, I haven't made it so it actual adds +1 when a predefined length is given. I've thought about this already but thank you

Comment: @wzsun Also, you should be using size_t for this, not int.

Comment: @Nick: Well, if he was doing length - position, I'd assume that is the length of original string... Though that's a good point.

Comment: @wzsun taking out the +1 for null from the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips however it still does not fix the error mentioned in my original post

Comment: I updated it but it's largely the same code, I commented why I haven't implemented the changes yet. But most of your edits would only occur if the user decided to make the startposition > then the length and the null terminator is taken care because its copied in the for loop

Comment: @wzsun that is not true, even if startposition is smaller than length, `length-startposition` will result into a smaller number than you need everytime (unless startposition is 0). Plus did you change `i=startposition` for `i=0`?